# Analyzing system throughput with Intel PMU

Tags: linux, memory, performance, redhat-enterprise-linux

I trust this *an appropriate* place for this question.  It's not programming related or I might have asked on Stackoverflow instead.  Nevertheless, here's the question.  I'm doing some benchmarking of network throughput.  I have two 40GbE NICs currently connected directly verifying bandwidth.  (To accomplish this, I'm using [iperf3](http://software.es.net/iperf/)).

My test systems are dual Xeon E5 2667 (from /proc/cpuinfo `model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 0 @ 2.90GHz`) exposing 24 logical processors.  There is a *NUMA hypercube* of two nodes with half the processors attached to each.  There is 32-GB of RAM in the form of non-ECC DDR3.  In each case, the 40GbE NIC is attached to a PCIe Gen 3 x8 slot which is associated to NUMA node 0.

When I perform a test with iperf3 with a minimum of options (essentially using defaults which is sufficient for my purposes), I'm unable see bandwidth for the TCP test rise above 21.x Gbps (ok, so, occasionally it gets above 21 but it's usually 21.x).  However, if I use the iperf3 `-A n` option which restricts `iperf3` to processor `<n>`, I see ~36 Gbps which is much more like what I'd expect.  I'd like to understand why.

I've experimented some with `numactl` to bind memory allocations, processor nodes and physical processor for `iperf3`.  Oddly, I cannot achieve the same throughput using `numactl` as I get using `iperf3`'s `-A` option.  Fiddling with various things/options (see [numactl man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=numactl&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=CentOS%207.1&arch=default&format=html) for more), chiefly the `--physcpubind=<n>`, `--cpunodebind=<n>` and `--membind=<n>` I cannot achieve any more than ~31Gbps in this test.  I'd like to understand why.

To that end, I've begun using the `perf` package linux provides.  However, I'm not finding much in the mountain of documentation available from either Linux or Intel about the PMU things available.  Oh it explains how to run it, but little is said about *what things actually mean*.  As an example, `bus-cycles` appears in both "Hardware Events" and "Kernel PMU Events."  What's the difference?  `perf list` delineates the "events" which can be monitored; it's lengthy.  Documentation I've found from Intel for the Xeon E5 2667 (which I believe is a Haswell setup) shows that various NUMA related things are supported and `perf list` shows `uncore_imc_0/cas_count_read/` and `uncore_qpi_0/drs_data/` (among many others) which should be related to this.  Yet, when I run `iperf3` attempting to monitor this, I get that it isn't supported.  For example:

```
$ perf stat -e uncore_qpi_0/drs_data/ -- iperf3 -c 192.168.0.244 -A 0
.... program output ....
Performance counter stats for 'iperf3 -c 192.168.0.244 -A 0':

  <not supported>      uncore_qpi_0/drs_data/
```

However, the docs show it should be.  Is there some way to find out what is supported by my processor without running the program only to find out afterword that it isn't?  Would anyone have suggestions for metrics that are important in understanding the disparity?  (Tagged with RHEL because that is the target platform for the solution.)